# How to configure angular universal development server for chrome inspect tools and docker?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, google-chrome, angular-universal

I’m currently working on my server side rendering with angular universal. My application currently sometimes breaks during the build process because my docker nodejs container says that my JavaScript heap is exceeded. So now I‘m looking for a way to inspect my code during runtime to avoid memory leaks.

Usually I would inspect my nodejs server with chrome inspect tools.
I discovered, that the nodejs inspect flag can be set by setting „inspect“ to true in my angular.json under
serve-ssr -> configurations -> development -> options.

So this way I was able to expose the endpoint for my Chrome inspect tools on 127.0.0.1:9229.

Now, my angular dev environment is running inside a docker container due to network dependencies to my API. So I’d need to connect to the nodejs debugger through docker.
My docker container publicly exposes 0.0.0.0:9229 but the angular universal debugger runs on 127.0.0.1:9229. The usual node cli flag „inspect-brk=0.0.0.0“ does not seem to be configurable through my angular.json.

So my question is:
How do i generally inspect the angular universal nodejs server or how can I configure nodejs and the debugging endpoint inside docker?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You said the error occurs during build time. Why don't you just raise nodejs memory limit for the build?

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your comment. Yes, this is my temporary solution right now. I was not sure whether this could be a sign of any memory leaks during runtime of my SSR. Inspecting the angular universal nodejs server during development is something that could be very useful anyway. As described above i wasn't able to connect to that server inside my docker container yet